# What's the equivalent to PropertyInfo.ReflectedType in .NET Core / .NET Standard?

Tags: .net, reflection, .net-core, system.reflection, .net-standard

I need something like what `PropertyInfo.ReflectedType` does in the full framework.

For now I've been not able to figure out what can be the alternative to the whole property of `PropertyInfo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReflectedType is not supported in .NET Core and was "intentionally excluded" as guys from Microsoft says. This [question on github](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/926) contains a link to blog that explains the reason but is broken right now...

You may look on PRs like [Nunit. Eliminate use of ReflectedType in preparation for ASP .Net 5 support](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/pull/797) or [AutoFixture. Support for CoreCLR](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/404) to get ideas how to adapt your code. In general, the working solution is to remove all using of `ReflectedType` property and instead hold and use the reference to the the object for which the type was got (reflected object).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the effort. Yeah, actually before posting this question I was aware of some of your provided links. In summary, I believe that you should provide the alternative to `ReflectedType` in your answer, otherwise all these links can end up broken in a while.

Comment: Since the official statement about how to solve this is to hold a reference to the object for which the type was got, you may edit your answer and I'll accept your answer!