# MethodInfo ReflectedType in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-core

How can we replace `MethodInfo.ReflectedType` in .NET Core?

In .NET Core 1.1 `MethodInfo.ReflectedType` is still unavailable.
What is it alternative?

Comment: I assume the same reason and workaround as for  `PropertyInfo.ReflectedType`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42126798/whats-the-equivalent-to-propertyinfo-reflectedtype-in-net-core-net-standard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a neat site, [APIsOf.Net](https://apisof.net), where you can find the full info about classes availabily in .Net world.

As it seems for now, the abstract property [`MemberInfo.ReflectedType`](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Reflection.MemberInfo.ReflectedType) will be available only in 2.0 version of `.Net Standard`, so be all of it's implementations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I looked at this site previously but really the question how to replace the code for .NET Core 1.1

Comment: And the answer is either wait for release or create a pull request to existing code